# PHP CodeIgniter-combobox value not getting update in database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, combobox

I have a table view of some products having Edit and Delete options.When i click on Edit it redirects to another page and shows particular data.There is one field named **Product Category** which shows product category of product in combobox e.g. Pizza.

Now,the problem begins.Suppose i select Sandwich instead of Pizza from combobox and try to update that value in database.It's not update anything.

I have used Codeigniter for this project,so i want solution for the same.I have searched in Google as well from other help,but hard luck. I am not getting proper solution.

Any reply would be appreciate.

My Code Snippet is given below.

**1)Controller**

```
function products_edit($product_id)
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->helper('form');  
    $this->load->helper('html');    
    $this->load->model('products_model');
    $data=$this->products_model->general();
    $product = $this->products_model->get_product($product_id);
    $category['categories']=$this->products_model->get_category();
    $this->data1['title'] = 'Edit Product';

    //validate form input
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Product name', 'required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'required|xss_clean');
    //$this->form_validation->set_rules('category', 'Category', 'required|xss_clean');
    //$this->form_validation->set_rules('extras', 'Extras', 'required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'Price', 'required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('is_featured', 'Is Featured', 'required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('prorder', 'Order', 'required|xss_clean');

    if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
    {       
        $data1 = array(
            'product_name'=> $this->input->post('name'),
            'product_desc'=> $this->input->post('description'),
            'product_category'=> $this->input->post('category'),
            'extras'=> $this->input->post('extras'),
            'price'=> $this->input->post('price'),
            'is_featured'=> $this->input->post('is_featured'),
            'prorder' => $this->input->post('order'),
        );

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === true)
        {
            $this->products_model->updateproducts($product_id, $data1);

            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', "<p>Product updated successfully.</p>");

            redirect('products_controller/products_edit/'.$product_id);
        }           
    }

    $this->data1['message'] = (validation_errors() ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message'));

    $this->data1['product'] = $product;
    //$this->data1['category']=$category;

    //display the edit product form     
    $this->data1['name'] = array(
        'name'      => 'name',
        'id'        => 'name',
        'type'      => 'text',
        'style'     => 'width:300px;',
        'value'     => $this->form_validation->set_value('name', $product['product_name']),
    );

    $this->data1['description'] = array(
        'name'      => 'description',
        'id'        => 'description',
        'type'      => 'text',
        'cols'      =>  40,
        'rows'      =>  5,
        'value'     => $this->form_validation->set_value('description', $product['product_desc']),
    );

        $category1=$this->products_model->get_category();
        $category1['value']=set_value('category',$product['product_category']);
        $temp=array(
        '1'=>$category1['value'],
        );
        $category1=array_diff($category1,$temp);
        $category1['value']=set_value('category',$product['product_category']);

        $this->data1['category']=$category1;



    //$this->data1['category'] = array(
        //'name'    => 'category',
    //  'id'        => 'category',
    //  'type'      => 'text',
    //  'style'     => 'width:300px;',
    //'value'   => $this->form_validation->set_value('category',$category['categories']),set_value('category',$product['product_category']),


        //$this->data1['category']= $this->form_validation->set_value('category',$category['categories']);
        //);


    $this->data1['extras'] = array(
        //'name'    => 'extras',
        //'id'      => 'extras',
        //'type'    => 'text',
        //'style'       => 'width:300px;',
        'value'     => $this->form_validation->set_value('extras', $product['extras']),
    );

    $this->data1['price'] = array(
        'name'      => 'price',
        'id'        => 'price',
        'type'      => 'text',
        'style'     => 'width:40px;text-align: right',
        'value'     => $this->form_validation->set_value('price', $product['price']),
    );

    $this->data1['is_featured'] = array(
        'name'      => 'is_featured',
        'id'        => 'is_featured',
        'type'      => 'text',
        'style'     => 'width:40px;text-align: right',
        'value'     => $this->form_validation->set_value('isfeatured', $product['is_featured']),
    );

    $this->data1['prorder'] = array(
        'name'  => 'prorder',
        'id'    => 'prorder',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'style' => 'width:40px;',
        'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('prorder', $product['prorder']),
    );
    $this->load->view('products_edit', $this->data1);
}
```

**2)Model**

```
function get_product($product_id) {
    $this->db->select('product_id,product_name,product_desc,product_category,extras,price,is_featured,prorder');
    $this->db->where('product_id', $product_id);
    $this->db->distinct('product_category');
    $query = $this->db->get('product');
    return $query->row_array();

}

function updateproducts($product_id, $data)
{
    $this->db->where('product_id', $product_id);
    $this->db->update('product', $data);
}
```

**3)View**

```
<?php $product_id = $product['product_id']; ?>
<?php echo form_open("products_controller/products_edit/$product_id");?>
<table width="500" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" align="center">
<tr>
<td width="130" align="right"> Product Name: </td>
<td><?php echo form_input($name); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="130" align="right"> Product Description: </td>
<td><?php echo form_textarea($description); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">Product Category:</td>
<td>
<?php echo form_dropdown("product_id",$category,'value')?>      
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">Extras:</td>
<td><?php echo  form_dropdown("product_id",$extras,"#","id='product_id'");?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">Price:</td>
<td><?php echo form_input($price); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">Is Featured:</td>
<td><?php echo form_input($is_featured); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">Order:</td>
<td><?php echo form_input($prorder); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit');?>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table align="center">
<tr>
<td>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
<?php echo form_open("products_controller/products_search");?>
<?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Back');?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [**update multiple select values in mysql database using codeigniter**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20291225/update-multiple-select-values-in-mysql-database-using-codeigniter/20291301)

Comment: @dianuj.Thank you for your reply.But, its not proper solution for me.

Comment: Have you read the comments of answer you need that type of logic

Comment: @dianuj,yes friend i have read all the comments.But, my problem is different.I want solution for combobox. Other field values are updating,but combobox value is not updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use below code,

```
$test = array();
$count=count($category['categories']);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
 $test[$i] = array($category['categories'][$i] => $category['categories'][$i]);
} 
$this->data['category']=set_value('category',$test);
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the value of `<?php echo form_dropdown("product_id",$category,'value')?>`
you have to write `$this->input->post('product_id')` this will get you the product id and then you can use it to update db

Comment: but friend other values are updating, only combobox value is not.

Comment: i have gone through your code several times. i can see that you are accessing your product_category value by [link]'product_category'=> $this->input->post('category'), but i didnt find any dropdown named 'category' can you pls check this..thanks

Comment: $this->data1['category']=$category1; this statement is combobox named 'category'